# Why TypeScript showing 'product' does not exist on type '{...}' when 'product' does exist?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

Prisma model:

```
model Product {
  id          String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name        String
  description String
  price       Float
  image       String

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  cart Cart[]
}

model Cart {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  userId String @db.ObjectId
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  productId String  @db.ObjectId
  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])

  quantity  Int      @default(1)
  dateAdded DateTime @default(now())
}
```

CartItem Component:

```
import { Cart } from "@prisma/client";

const CartItem = ({ cartItem }: { cartItem: Cart }) => {

  const { image, name, description, price } = cartItem.product;
  return (...)
}
```

the error is in `cartItem.product`

Error is :

> Property 'product' does not exist on type '{ id: string; userId: string; productId: string; quantity: number; dateAdded: Date; }'. Did you mean 'productId'?ts(2551)
> index.d.ts(4545, 7): 'productId' is declared here.

It is clear in model that product exists. Then why is it throwing an error?

Answer (score 1):

In Prisma, when you define a relation between two models, the generated types typically do not automatically include the related fields. Instead, you need to explicitly fetch the related data using either eager loading or lazy loading.

To resolve this issue, you can modify the query that retrieves the `Cart` items to include the related `Product` data. Here's how you can do it using eager loading with Prisma.

Try this way :-

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getCartItemsWithProducts() {
  const cartItems = await prisma.cart.findMany({
    include: {
      product: true, // This includes the related Product data
    },
  });
  return cartItems;
}
```

Also try running `npx prisma generate`

After running the command, TypeScript should recognize the product property on the Cart type.